# HTML markup for BEM block

Tags: html, bem

[The **BEM** methodology](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/)  says:

> In HTML, the block markup is repeated every time the block appears on the page.

That is, you can’t do this?

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu__logo></div>
    <a class="menu__link></a>
</div>
<div class="menu">
    <button class="menu__exit-button></button>
</div>
```

Since the markup in the same block is different

Comment: Linking to some [basic information about what BEM is](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/) in your question would be a kindness for those unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A block can have different markups inside depending on the situation.

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__logo">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>
  <nav class="menu__nav">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">About</a>
  </nav>
  <button class="menu__exit-button"></button>
</div>

Do you have use case/design we can look at?
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do it like this instead of having two blocks

```
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu__logo></div>
    <a class="menu__link></a>
    <button class="menu__exit-button></button>
</div>
```

you attributes are missing the closing quotations

Comment: It's just a sample. The question is whether the same block can have a different markup inside